# Python File Read Error

Tags: python, passwords, md5

I am trying to make an MD5 password cracker using a wordlist. The MD5 hashes I am comparing with have been obtained from the HTML of a website that I have been tasked to gather information from. So far I have successfully gathered the MD5 hashes and I have obtained a word list that I loop through and successfully create hashes of. However, when trying to compare it with the hashes that I currently have it only finds one results (even though I know it is four). I could be doing something incredibly stupid, but would like some suggestions.

```
def FindandCrackHash(content):
    # Find hashes
    attempt = 0
    contentHash = content
    hashList = []
    crackedHashes = []
    contentHash = re.findall(r'[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}', contentHash.decode())
    for h in contentHash:
        h = h.lower()
        hashList.append(h)
    print('')
    print(f'[+] {len(hashList)} MD5 Hashes Found:')
    for hashes in hashList:
        print(f'"{hashes}"')
    with open("C:\\Users\\Rory Gracey\\Desktop\\Napier CourseWork 2\\rockyou1.txt", 'r') as wordList:
        for line in wordList:
            md5Hash = hashlib.md5(line.encode('utf-8'))
            hashToCompare = md5Hash.hexdigest()
            compHash = str(hashToCompare)
            print(line) if compHash in hashList else None
[+] 4 MD5 Hashes Found:
"fea0f1f6fede90bd0a925b4194deac11"
"d1133275ee2118be63a577af759fc052"
"5badcaf789d3d1d09794d8f021f40f0e"
"5fcfd41e547a12215b173ff47fdd3739"
 trustno1
```

This is what I have currently got. Any help would be much appreciated. CHEERS!

Comment: What happens if you debug with the known 4 hashes, and print each, as well as the value being compared against?  Are they definitely the same?  Are you comparing the correct values?

Comment: On a sidenote - are you stripping newlines before you compare?